# Cannot cast array data from dtype('float32') to dtype('int64') according to the rule 'safe'

Tags: python, geotiff-tiff, convert, text

I'm trying to use a script 'format_veg_params.py' that takes geotiff data for vegetation parameterization and converts it to the needed text format for the VIC model (a model that uses remote sensing data to calculate the hydraulic balance in a watershed).
Usage:

```
 python format_veg_params.py <template raster> <land cover raster>
<output veg parameter file> <land cover classification scheme>
```

The commande Line Used:

```
$ python format_veg_params.py
../data/input/gis/Nyando_grid.tif
../data/input/gis/Nyando_basin_LC_IGBP.tif
../data/input/veg.param IGBP
```

running the script on terminal, gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "format_veg_params.py", line 180, in <module>
    main()
  File "format_veg_params.py", line 174, in main
    format_veg_params(sys.argv[1],sys.argv[2],sys.argv[3],sys.argv[4])
  File "format_veg_params.py", line 120, in format_veg_params
    clsAttributes)-1)].ravel()).argmax()
TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('float32') to dtype('int64') according to the rule 'safe'
```

I'd like to know what the problem is and how to solve it.

the script of 'format_veg_params.py' is as follows:

```
# import dependencies
import os
import sys
import json
import numpy as np
from osgeo import gdal
from osgeo.gdalnumeric import *  
from osgeo.gdalconst import *

def format_veg_params(basinMask,lcData,outVeg,scheme='IGBP'):
    """
    FUNCTION: format_veg_params
    ARGUMENTS: basinMask - path to basin template raster
               lcData - path to land cover raster
               outveg - path output vegetation parameter file
    KEYWORDS:  scheme - Abbreviation of land cover classification scheme the 
                        input land cover data is formatted in
    RETURNS: n/a
    NOTES: Returns no variables but writes an output file
    """

    # define script file path for relative path definitions
    __location__ = os.path.realpath(
    os.path.join(os.getcwd(), os.path.dirname(__file__)))

    # get land cover classification scheme and create path to lookup table
    if scheme == 'IGBP':
        attriFile = os.path.join(__location__,'veg_type_attributes_igbp.json')
    elif scheme == 'GLCC':
        attriFile = os.path.join(__location__,'veg_type_attributes_glcc.json')
    elif scheme == 'IPCC':
        attriFile = os.path.join(__location__,'veg_type_attributes_ipcc.json')
    else:
        raise SyntaxError('Land cover classification scheme not supported')

    band = 1 # constant variable for reading in data

    # open/read veg scheme json file
    with open(attriFile) as data_file:    
        attriData = json.load(data_file)

    # pass look up information into variable
    clsAttributes = attriData['classAttributes']

    # create list of input raster files
    infiles = [os.path.join(__location__,basinMask),
               os.path.join(__location__,lcData)]

    try: # try to read in the raster data

        # read basin grid raster
        ds = gdal.Open(infiles[0],GA_ReadOnly)
        b1 = ds.GetRasterBand(band)
        mask = BandReadAsArray(b1)
        maskRes = ds.GetGeoTransform()[1]
        ds = None
        b1 = None

        # read land cover raster
        ds = gdal.Open(infiles[1],GA_ReadOnly)
        b1 = ds.GetRasterBand(band)
        lccls = BandReadAsArray(b1)  
        clsRes = ds.GetGeoTransform()[1]
        ds = None
        b1 = None

    # if not working, give error message
    except AttributeError:
        raise IOError('Raster file input error, check that all paths are correct')

    ratio = maskRes/clsRes # get ratio of high resoltion to low resolution

    # get file path to output file
    vegfile = os.path.join(__location__,outVeg)

    # check if the output parameter file exists, if so delete it
    if os.path.exists(vegfile)==True:
        os.remove(vegfile)

    try: # try to write output veg parameter file

        # open output file for writing
        with open(vegfile, 'w') as f:

            cnt = 1 # grid cell id counter

            # loop over each pixel in the template raster
            for i in range(mask.shape[0]):
                y1 = int(i*ratio)
                y2 = int(y1+ratio)
                for j in range(mask.shape[1]):
                    x1 = int(j*ratio)
                    x2 = int(x1+ratio)

                    # get land cover data within template raster pixel
                    tmp = lccls[y1:y2,x1:x2]

                    # if not a mask value...
                    if mask[i,j] == 1:
                        # if there are nodata values...
                        if np.any(tmp>len(clsAttributes)-1)==True:
                            # ...find where they are... 
                            negdx = np.where(tmp>len(clsAttributes)-1)
                            try:
                                # ...and calculate hisogram for only data values
                                tmp[negdx] = np.bincount(tmp[np.where(tmp<len(
                                                clsAttributes)-1)].ravel()).argmax()
                            except ValueError:
                                tmp[negdx] = 0
                        uniqcnt = np.unique(tmp) # number of unique values
                        clscnt = np.bincount(tmp.ravel())

                        # check if there is only 1 value in unique value array
                        if type(uniqcnt).__name__ == 'int':
                            Nveg = 1 # if so, only 1 value
                        else:
                            Nveg = len(uniqcnt) # if not, n veg equal to unique values

                        # write the grid cell id and number of classes    
                        f.write('{0} {1}\n'.format(cnt,Nveg))

                        # if there is vegetation data...
                        if Nveg != 0:
                            # ...loop over each class...
                            for t in range(uniqcnt.size):
                                # ...and grab the parameter attributes
                                vegcls = int(uniqcnt[t]) # class value
                                Cv = np.float(clscnt[uniqcnt[t]])/np.float(clscnt.sum()) # percent coverage
                                attributes = clsAttributes[vegcls]['properties'] # intermediate variale
                                rdepth1 = str(attributes['rootd1']) # rooting depth layer 1
                                rfrac1 = str(attributes['rootfr1']) # rooting fraction layer 1
                                rdepth2 = str(attributes['rootd2']) # rooting depth layer 2
                                rfrac2 = str(attributes['rootfr2']) # rooting fraction layer 2
                                rdepth3 = str(attributes['rootd3']) # rooting depth layer 3
                                rfrac3 = str(attributes['rootfr3']) # rooting fraction layer 3

                                # write the veg class information
                                f.write('\t{0} {1:.4f} {2} {3} {4} {5} {6} {7}\n'.format(vegcls,Cv,rdepth1,rfrac1,rdepth2,rfrac2,rdepth3,rfrac3))           

                    cnt+=1 # plus one to grid cell id counter

    # except raise an error when it doesn't work
    except IOError:
        raise IOError('Cannot write output file, error with output veg parameter file path')    

    return

def main():
    n_args = len(sys.argv)

    # Check user inputs
    if n_args != 5:
        print("Wrong user input")
        print("Script writes the vegetation parameter file for the VIC model")
        print("usage: python format_veg_params.py <template raster> <land cover raster> <output veg parameter file> <land cover classification scheme>")
        print("Exiting system...")
        sys.exit()

    else:
        # Pass command line arguments into function        
        format_veg_params(sys.argv[1],sys.argv[2],sys.argv[3],sys.argv[4])

    return

# Execute the main level program if run as standalone    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a type cast error at this line:

```
  tmp[negdx] = np.bincount(tmp[np.where(tmp<len(
                                           clsAttributes)-1)].ravel()).argmax()
```

it means it is expecting an integer value at some point in this instruction, but there is a floating point value instead.

But it's impossible to tell without having a reproducable example (the GeoTIFF file and the rest of the parameters you use to run it).

Comment: Can you tell me how I can do to show you the parameters I used so that you better identify the problem ?

Comment: Can you copy and paste the command line you use and upload somewhere the geotiff files used?

Comment: $ python format_veg_params.py
../data/input/gis/Nyando_grid.tif
../data/input/gis/Nyando_basin_LC_IGBP.tif
../data/input/veg.param IGBP